# 1d numpy array with enough elements not resizing as expected

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, reshape

I just started working with numpy arrays in conjunction with panda dataframes, and I am working on a practice project, but have hit a bit of a problem. I have a panda dataframe which I pass the rows of to a function to do some work on it. The function takes in two different arrays one labeled best and worst and then creates a new vector to compare sums against. From there it will return either the current array that the pandas.apply has passed or it will return the new vector based on which sum() is the lowest. This creates a new python array which needs to be a matrix of 20x5 at the end. The function works fine, but the returned dataframe needs to be converted to a python array of size (20 x 5) for further work, which when np.array() is called, it converts it into an array of size (20,). I figured just using .reshape(20,5) would work since it has enough elements to work with, but it does not, it just fails on run. Any help is appreciated as I can't find anything that's helping me understand why this is happening.

(the error, as many could guess by reading above, is: "cannot reshape array of size 20 into shape (20,5)" )

code except from my program that shows it (can run on it's own):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=22)
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((20,5)))

def new_vectors(current, best, worst):
    #convert current to numpy array 
    current = current.to_numpy()

    #construct a new vector to check
    new = np.add(current, np.subtract((rng.random()*(np.subtract(best, np.absolute(current)))), ((rng.random()*(np.subtract(worst, np.absolute(current)))))))

    #get the new sum for the new and old vectors
    summed = current.sum()
    newsummed = new.sum()

    #return the smallest one
    return np.add(((newsummed < summed)*(new)), ((newsummed > summed)*(current))).flatten()


z = np.array(df.apply(new_vectors, args=(df.iloc[0].to_numpy(), df.iloc[11].to_numpy()), axis=1))
z.reshape(20,5) #I know reshape() creates a copy, just here to show it doesn't work regardless
```

Comment: `z.reshape(20,5)` returns a new array.  It does not work in-place.  Read the docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: You return an `array of arrays` of shape `(20,)`. You can't reshape `(20,)` to `(20,5)`

Comment: to hpaulj, I know it doesn't, I just put it in there to show it doesn't work at all: aka it will never get past that line.

Comment: to Michael, is there anyway to convert the data to a different shape then, or create a different array of size 20x5 with these 100 data pieces mapped to it?

Comment: @Guardian - Maybe if you make it clear what you want your function to do (*manipulate it a bit and return it* is pretty vague).

Comment: can you provide an example of the results of just a `(3,2)` input array?

Comment: to Michael, I changed it to read what the function does, but the function is working fine, it's just the format of the output data I'm struggling with. To ti7: an output with a 3,2 array is: [array([ 0.52061544, -0.05277374]) array([0.25730506, 0.37746578])
 array([0.53714549, 0.72159349])]

Comment: If something doesn't work, you should show the error (with traceback), or show the wrong result.  Don't expect us to run your code to see how it behaves ourselves.

Comment: added for you hpaulj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original dataframe - with reduced length for display purposes:

```
In [628]: df = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((4,5)))
In [629]: df
Out[629]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.891169  0.134904  0.515261  0.975586  0.150426
1  0.834185  0.671914  0.072134  0.170696  0.923737
2  0.065445  0.356001  0.034787  0.257711  0.213964
3  0.790341  0.080620  0.111369  0.542423  0.199517
```

The next frame:

```
In [631]: df1=df.apply(new_vectors, args=(df.iloc[0].to_numpy(), df.iloc[3].to_numpy()), axis=1)
In [632]: df1
Out[632]: 
0    [0.891168725430691, 0.13490384333565053, 0.515...
1    [0.834184861872087, 0.6719141503303373, 0.0721...
2    [0.065444520313796, 0.35600115939269394, 0.034...
3    [0.7903408924058509, 0.08061955595765169, 0.11...
dtype: object
```

Note that it has 1 column, that contains arrays.  Make an array from it:

```
In [633]: df1.to_numpy()
Out[633]: 
array([array([0.89116873, 0.13490384, 0.51526113, 0.97558562, 0.15042584]),
       array([0.83418486, 0.67191415, 0.07213404, 0.17069617, 0.92373724]),
       array([0.06544452, 0.35600116, 0.03478695, 0.25771129, 0.21396367]),
       array([0.79034089, 0.08061956, 0.1113691 , 0.54242262, 0.19951741])],
      dtype=object)
```

That is (4,) object dtype.  That dtype is important.  Even though the elements all have 5 elements themselves, `reshape` does not work across that "object" boundary.  We can't reshape it to (4,5).

But we can `concatenate` those arrays:

```
In [636]: np.vstack(df1.to_numpy())
Out[636]: 
array([[0.89116873, 0.13490384, 0.51526113, 0.97558562, 0.15042584],
       [0.83418486, 0.67191415, 0.07213404, 0.17069617, 0.92373724],
       [0.06544452, 0.35600116, 0.03478695, 0.25771129, 0.21396367],
       [0.79034089, 0.08061956, 0.1113691 , 0.54242262, 0.19951741]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The previous answer defintiely would have worked, but thanks for taking the time to explain why the numpy array couldn't be reshaped, so I understand the behavior better in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the reshape manually.

1. Delete `z.reshape(20,5)`. This is not going to work with an array of arrays.
2. After applying the function, use this instead:

   ```
   # Create a empty matrix with desired size
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(20,5))
    # Iterate over z and assign each array to a row in the numpy matrix.
    for i,arr in enumerate(z):
         matrix[i] = arr
   ```

If you don't know the desired size for the matrix. Create the matrix as `matrix = np.zeros(shape=df.shape)`.

All the code used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=22)
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((20,5)))

def new_vectors(current, best, worst):
    #convert current to numpy array 
    current = current.to_numpy()

    #construct a new vector to check
    new = np.add(current, np.subtract((rng.random()*(np.subtract(best, np.absolute(current)))), ((rng.random()*(np.subtract(worst, np.absolute(current)))))))

    #get the new sum for the new and old vectors
    summed = current.sum()
    newsummed = new.sum()

    #return the smallest one
    return np.add(((newsummed < summed)*(new)), ((newsummed > summed)*(current))).flatten()


z = np.array(df.apply(new_vectors, args=(df.iloc[0].to_numpy(), df.iloc[11].to_numpy()), axis=1))

matrix = np.zeros(shape=df.shape)

for i,arr in enumerate(z):
     matrix[i] = arr
```

Comment: I figured this is what I would need to do, but I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a numpy specific way that would be less verbose that I should be using to remedy this. Either way, thanks!